# How to Pass Object Values to Children in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-select

I am trying to pass an object from Parent to Child as described in this [article](https://dev.to/dipakkr/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-other-component-in-react-35i2).

I am new to React JS and am probably missing something simple here.

The goal of this is to have a select list of "Industries" that passes the selected industry to a select list of "Categories". The selected Category would then populate a table.

I am getting the error that `this.props.selectedIndustry` doesn't exist on compile.

Here is my code:

```
    class CategoryFilter extends React.Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          industrySelect: this.props.selectedIndustry
        }
        console.log(this.props.selectedIndustry)
      }
    
      render() {
  
        const { selectedCategory } = this.state;
        const categories = utmcategories.filter(function(i) {return i.industry==this.props.selectedIndustry})

        return (
          <Select options={categories} onChange={this.handleCategoryChange}
          />
        );
      }
    
    class IndustryFilter extends React.Component {
    
      state = {
        selectedIndustry: null,
      };
    
      handleIndustryChange = (selectedIndustry) => {
        this.setState({ selectedIndustry });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedIndustry);
      }
    
      render() {
    
        const { selectedIndustry } = this.state;    
        const industries = utmindustries;
    
        return (
          <div>
            <Select options={industries} 
            onChange={this.handleIndustryChange}
            autoFocus={true}
            />
            <CategoryFilter selectedIndustry={selectedIndustry}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

I modified the code to narrow down the issue and made my CategoryFilter this:

```
function CategoryFilter(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.filteredIndustry}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But still got the error:

*`"Objects are not valid as a React Child."`*

Comment: try `props.selectedIndustry` without `this` at constructor

Comment: I get the error "Reference Error: props is not defined"

Comment: Components do not have access to their parent's props when they are initialised - the earliest you can get them is inside `componentDidMount`. Also, not a good idea to store props directly in state like that - only new data derived from that prop belongs in a component's state.

Comment: Thanks and I stripped the child component down and updated the post above. Shouldn't I be able to access this value here?

Comment: console log `filteredIndustry` above the render to see what you're dealing with. As the error suggests, if it's an object/array it can't be rendered. Looks like you're on the right track though.

Comment: I was trying to pass an object to a child when it wanted an array. Fixing this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are initialising `selectedIndustry` to `null` here:

```
state = {
    selectedIndustry: null,
  };
```

and then passing it in as a prop to `<CategoryFilter>`

> I am getting the error that this.props.selectedIndustry doesn't exist
> on compile. Here is my code

Not quite sure that the 'error' you are getting is actually an error. Seems like it may be the expected behaviour. Could you please show us the error message exactly?

I would expect `this.props.selectedIndustry` to be defined as `null` after `<CatergoryFilter>` has mounted. You should try initialising it to a value e.g. "Default Industry" and see if that `console.log(this.props.selectedIndustry)` in the constructor is printing "Default Industry". If not, I would suspect that the `this` context has not been initialised until after the constructor has returned. Try logging this value in the render() method instead.